# What is the full extent of Cypher's omnilingualism?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Douglas Aaron Ramsey, also known as Doug or Cypher has the mutant power of omnilingualism, aka understanding pretty much any language, both verbal and written. This makes him something of a laughing stock until the writers began to drastically expand his abilities. I've read that he can communicate with computers, spot the structural weaknesses of buildings, can deactivate electronic devices and even understand (and maybe use) magical languages.

But what is the full extent of his powers? He can read body language to predict how enemies will attack him, but could he keep up with a very skilled enemy and land blows himself, a bit like how the powers of Midnighter from The Authority work? Are there any other things that he can do with his powers, like communicate with the atoms that constitute for example a wall and ask them to move aside, creating a hole that he can pass through? Or maybe communicate with the neurons inside a human brain to either read minds or maybe even control people? Or am I reading too far into this? Has a hard limit of his powers ever been established?

Comment: Yes. As plot demands. No hard limits have been demonstrated.

Comment: Wow. Pick a question, any question. This is either too broad or opinion based, I couldn't decide which one fit.

Comment: Not every super-power must be useful in battle. Being able to understand any form of structured communication would make him an invaluable resource.